# File Not Uploading To Google Bucket

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

When i try to upload file to google cloud bucket i'm receiving following error "Cannot use ACL API to set object policy when object policies are disabled" .Need help to solve this error.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you told us what you've tried so far and gave a bit more detail about the error - is there a stack trace? Where exactly are you getting this? Any relevant screenshots you could share?

Comment: Hi paul, i am working on an ocr project. i want to store the uploaded file (PDF file) in google bucket for later use. When i upload the file using postman i am getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paul Benn mentioned providing as much information as you can about your issue is really helpful for us in order to be able to understand your situation.

But if I had to guess and from what I've been able to find out is that you are attempting to upload with ACL and have the bucket set to "Uniform" instead of "Fine-Grained".

The [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access?hl=en_US&_ga=2.38967843.-1031799667.1573225671#overview) states this:

> If you enable uniform bucket-level access, you revoke access from users who gain their access solely through object ACLs. Be sure that you read considerations when migrating an existing bucket prior to enabling uniform bucket-level access.

If you provide us with more information we will surely be able to help you more.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks  for the timely help. we changed from "Uniform" to "Fine-Grained" as you suggested and its working.